# Sitecore Azure deployment failed : The password does not meet policy requirements

Tags: azure, installation, paas

I am trying to install Sitecore 9.0 Update-2 on Azure PaaS using MarketPlace but I am getting the below error during deployment:

[image]

> {"code":"c","message":"At least one resource deployment operation
>   failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage
>   details.","details":[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n \"status\":
>   \"Failed\",\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\":
>   \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n \"message\": \"The resource
>   operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n
>   \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"DeploymentFailed\",\r\n
>   \"message\": \"At least one resource deployment operation failed.
>   Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n
>   {\r\n \"code\": \"Conflict\",\r\n \"message\": \"{\r\n
>   \\"status\\": \\"Failed\\",\r\n \\"error\\": {\r\n
>   \\"code\\": \\"ResourceDeploymentFailure\\",\r\n
>   \\"message\\": \\"The resource operation completed with terminal
>   provisioning state 'Failed'.\\",\r\n \\"details\\": [\r\n
>   {\r\n \\"code\\": \\"PasswordNotComplex\\",\r\n
>   \\"message\\": \\"Password validation failed. The password does not
>   meet policy requirements because it is not complex enough.\\"\r\n
>   }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}

When I dig into the exception, I got to know this is because of `"The password does not meet policy requirements because it is not complex enough"`

I am not using the complex password, also at the time of filling the parameters, it didn't show me the strong password validation error,

[image]

There are three password parameters during the installation as below:

1. Sitecore Admin Password
2. SQL server password
3. certification password

I am not sure, which password policy is violating during the deployment, as it's not throwing the validation error individually.

But, once I provided the complex password, then it worked for me.